# moving lines from one window to another

Tags: vim

Is there a simple command that will move lines from one window to another. Currently I go to one window, yank the lines, and then paste in the other window.

I would like to know if I can do it without switching windows.

Comment: You should be more descriptive in your problem.  Are you trying to find an easier to way to cut and paste?

Comment: I am looking for something that doesn't require me to switch windows.

Comment: If you don't switch windows, how would Vim know where you wanted to paste?

Comment: Using the buffer numbers: move lines 10,15 from buffer 1 to line 35 after buffer 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do this sort of thing with a macro.  So to record a macro for a, qa.  Then yy to yank the line, :bnext to switch buffers, p to paste the line, then bnext again to switch back to the original buffer (on the line you started on).  Then hit q to stop recording.

So to copy, switch windows, paste then switch back, you just need to use @a.  Or map it to a function key (map  @a).

N.B. Just noticed in the comments you had multiple buffers, so obviously you would need to record your macro accordingly.

Comment: I guess, thats what I might have to do. Use macros or write a script.

Comment: I find it is pretty seamless doing it this way.  Vim macros are your friend ;).

Comment: It's so obvious, but for some odd reason, I'd never considered using macros which worked across different buffers until just now.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this mapping:

```
nmap <C-y> Y<C-w>wp<C-w>w
```

Comment: To yank, delete, switch window and then paste: `nmap <C-y> Ydd<C-w>wp<C-w>w`

Answer (score 1):

using vimdiff you can use diffput or diffget to copy changes between buffers. From the manual:

```
There are two commands to copy text from one buffer to another.  The result is
that the buffers will be equal within the specified range.


                        *:diffg* *:diffget*
:[range]diffg[et] [bufspec]
    Modify the current buffer to undo difference with another
    buffer.  If [bufspec] is given, that buffer is used.
    Otherwise this only works if there is one other buffer in diff
    mode.
    See below for [range].


                        *:diffpu* *:diffput*
:[range]diffpu[t] [bufspec]
    Modify another buffer to undo difference with the current
    buffer.  Just like ":diffget" but the other buffer is modified
    instead of the current one.
    See below for [range].
```

Comment: I'm learning vimdiff (I've used Beyond Compare to merge 
in Windows) and vimdiff happens to be a great tool for merging.
No programming, on the fly merging.  I don't want to write a 
script for this sort of thing.  Learning a few vi commands is not
very painful.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether this is possible. But here is an interesting post [about 100 Vim commands](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/100-vim-commands-every-programmer-should-know) every programmer should know if you are interested.